# Order by count of has_many :through items in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, count, associations, has-many-through

If I have 3 models:

Model `Section`

Model `User`

`has_many :votes`

Model `Vote`

`belongs_to :user`

and inside Model`Section`

```
has_many :users
has_many :votes, :through => :users
```

How to get the Sections list ordered by votes quantity using the `AR` associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reasonable way to do this is to use a subquery written as raw SQL for ordering the result as follows...

```
Section.order(
  '(select count(1) from votes inner join users on votes.user_id=users.id where users.section_id=sections.id)'
)
```

Comment: so ActiveRecord is not helping on this complex association case then?

Comment: Well, not for this particular sorting requirement anyway. It's presumably quite useful in regard to other ways that your application uses these models. There presumably *is* a way to implement this sorting via some byzantine combination of AR and Arel, but it's not worth the time and effort it would take to work that out -- and then it would not be especially legible or maintainable.

Comment: +1 Steve, very useful answer. I'm trying to do something similar but with another level of has_many through: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537378/ordering-nested-has-many-through-by-count-of-associations ]. Do you have any thoughts on how I can extend your SQL for that purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Section.joins(users: :votes).group(:id).order('COUNT(*)')
```